# R - multiple conditions within mutate function

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have the following dataframe (see the link : [image: response_accuracy]). Now, I would like to know whether, for each trial_number, the value in response_time_to_origin is contained between target_onset_plus200 and target_onset_plus1000 but according to multiple conditions :

if 76 <= trial_number <= 151, filter block == 1 and subblock == "A" and then check whether response_time_to_origin is between target_onset_plus200 and target_onset_plus1000. If so answer TRUE, if this happens for other blocks and subblock, answer FALSE.

else if 152 <= trial_number <= 227, filter block == 1 and subblock == "B" and then check whether response_time_to_origin is between target_onset_plus200 and target_onset_plus1000. If so answer TRUE, if this happens for other blocks and subblock, answer FALSE.

ETC.

I have tried to insert the following bit of code, which obviously does not work :

```
response_accuracy=data_out%>%     
   select(trial_number, response_time_to_origin)%>%     
   filter(!is.na(response_time_to_origin))%>%     
   mutate(list_windows_terminals = list(list_hit_windows))%>%      
   unnest(list_windows_terminals)%>%     
   group_by(block, subblock, trial_number)%>%     
   mutate(response_in_window = if(76 <= trial_number <= 151){     
      filter(block == 1 & subblock == "A") & response_time_to_origin >      
      target_onset_plus200 & response_time_to_origin < 
      target_onset_plus1000)})
```

Could you help me ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

It makes it a bit difficult to help you without the minimal example of data.

Try this code:

```
response_accuracy=data_out %>%     
   select(trial_number, response_time_to_origin) %>%     
   filter(!is.na(response_time_to_origin)) %>%     
   mutate(list_windows_terminals = list(list_hit_windows)) %>%      
   unnest(list_windows_terminals) %>%     
   group_by(block, subblock, trial_number) %>% 
   mutate(response_in_window = ifelse(between(trial_number, 76, 151) && block == 1 && subblock == "A", "TRUE", "FALSE")) %>%
   mutate(response_in_window = ifelse(between(trial_number, 152, 227) && block == 1 && subblock == "B", "TRUE", response_in_window))
```

If it doesn't work, you should provide a code to generate your dataframe for me to test.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work ! How could I send you my code to generate the df ? It is too long for the number of char. allowed in a comment !

Comment: @gaelle you can make a small chunk of code that generates a fraction of your data table and edit your original post to include it. If you need help, more information on reprex: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/10/how-to-make-a-reprex/

Comment: edv thanks a lot for your advice -- I ended up wrighting a new question which included the chunks of code and someone helped me. Thank you very much in any case ! Best regards

Comment: @gaelle No worries! Happy you found your answer!